# SharePoint 2013 Alert

Tags: sharepoint-alerts

I have an issue with my Alert, the issue I have is every time I click on an alert item it will take me to the record however the record is empty. When I look at the URL the ID is duplicated and when I remove the duplication it's fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was access mapping, I had to change the default alternate access mapping